# NameError in Controller with Ending 'y'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

By starting the page localhost:3000/ticker_activities I am getting a NameError in my TickerActivitiesController

> uninitialized constant TickerActivitiesController::Ticker_Activity

**app/controllers/ticker_activities_controller.rb:**

```
class TickerActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    @ticker_activities = Ticker_Activity.all

    ...
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :ticker_activities
```

**models/ticker_activity.rb**

```
class TickerActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
```

**Routes**

```
ticker_activities GET    /ticker_activities(.:format)                 ticker_activities#index
                                  POST   /ticker_activities(.:format)                 ticker_activities#create
              new_ticker_activity GET    /ticker_activities/new(.:format)             ticker_activities#new
             edit_ticker_activity GET    /ticker_activities/:id/edit(.:format)        ticker_activities#edit
                  ticker_activity GET    /ticker_activities/:id(.:format)             ticker_activities#show
                                  PUT    /ticker_activities/:id(.:format)             ticker_activities#update
                                  DELETE /ticker_activities/:id(.:format)             ticker_activities#destroy
```

I tried everything form 'Ticker_Activities.all', 'Ticker_Activitie.all', 'Ticker_Activiti.all'. Nothing worked.

Could it be that this has something to do with the 'y'- 'ies' ending of activity / activities?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> uninitialized constant TickerActivitiesController::Ticker_Activity

You need to change

```
@ticker_activities = Ticker_Activity.all
```

to

```
@ticker_activities = TickerActivity.all
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you